# Ubuntu failed to start: Detect the available GPU's and deal with any system changes

Tags: graphics, amd-graphics

I tried to install the propietary AMD Radeon drivers on Budgie 21.10. After uninstalling them (installation failed) I cannot reboot back into the system. Is there a way to get the ubuntu stock ATI Renoir drivers back into the system and boot up ?

Thanks
Peter

Comment: If you can make it to grub, you can interrupt the boot there, enter recovery mode, enable networking, drop to root shell prompt, and revert your changes.